# Filtering a list of strings by dynamic amounts of elements

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

I need to write a function that filters a list of strings by multiple conditions:

This would look this like this if I use one condition:

```
def get_newest(inputlist, filter_):
    small_list = [el for el in inputlist if filter_ in el]
    return small_list


smaller = get_newest(lines, "condition1")
smaller
```

However, the function has to be dynamic so the list comprehension would look like this for 2 arguments:

```
small_list = [el for el in inputlist if filter_ in el and filter_2 in el]
```

This is of course not dynamic.

Passing a list as a single argument results in an error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is your function.

```
def get_newest(inputlist, filters):
    return [x for x in inputlist if all(f in x for f in filters)]
```

`filters` is an iterable of filters, e.g. `['substr1', 'substr2']`.

Comment: @DataMastery just make sure you always pass a list, even when there's only one filter (`['substr1']`). Otherwise, `for f in filters` will iterate over the *characters* in the string.

Comment: yep, I already added a check to convert a string to a list :-)